# SwiftUI: Navigation link not work inside scrollView

Tags: ios, listview, scrollview, swiftui, xcode11

I have been nest a ScrollView inside a List and that ScrollView contains a NavigationLink, the links won’t navigate to the destination when tapped by the user.

```
var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
            List {

                HeaderSection()
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(title.explore)
                        .font(.custom(App.fontBold, size: 21.0))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.top, 5.0)
                        .padding(.bottom, 5.0)
                        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                             HStack {
                                ForEach(self.viewModel.photos) { photo in
                                    NavigationLink(destination: ExploreDetails(photo: photo)) {
                                        ExploreView(photo: photo)
                                    }
                                 }
                            }
                        }
                }

                ForEach(viewModel.photos) { photo in
                        ImageRow(photo: photo)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.showModal.toggle()
                                self.selectedPhoto = photo
                        }

                }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: profileButton)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal, onDismiss:{ print("dissmiss")} ) {
               ContentDetailsView(photo: self.selectedPhoto!)
            }
    }
}
```

How can navigate when nesting a ScrollView inside a List?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Xcode 11 beta 6 it’s a bug. If you go to this tutorial https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/composing-complex-interfaces (that basically explains how to do exactly the same things you are trying to do) and you scroll down you can read:

> Note
>
> In Xcode 11 beta 6, if you nest a ScrollView inside a List and
>   that ScrollView contains a NavigationLink, the links won’t navigate to
>   the destination when tapped by the user.

Comment: I'm using XCode11.0 beta 5.

Comment: @Ashish I suggest you rewrite your code step by step to see when the issue shows up. I guess that NavigationView->ScrollView->HStack->ForEach->NavigationLink should work fine. Then you can try adding the List and eventually the VStack. Anyway: your layout seems a bit confusing, can you show us exactly what you're trying to get? (I mean visually). Are you trying to develop a vertical list of horizontal scroll views?

Comment: @Ashish I can't test directly on my xCode because I'm on xCode 11 beta 6, but can you try to remove the VStack and see if something changes? I'm asking because that VStack seems the only real difference between your code and the code in the Apple tutorial I posted in my answer. You can even try that tutorial and see if it works for you (on Beta 5).

Comment: @Ashish are you talking about the VStack removal or the Apple tutorial?

Comment: I try with the Apple tutorial, it is also not working. might be it an open bug from apple.

Comment: Xcode 11 (release) version seems to still have this problem

Comment: I'm following the tutorial too. I encounter the same issue. So if I preview the `CategoryRow.swift` which includes `ScrollView -> HStack -> ForEach -> NavigationLink` as shown in tutorial example, the `NavigationLink` does not work. However, if don't change anything, previewing from the `ContentView.swift`, the same `NavigationLink` will work. (That's why I'm here). So if  go back to `CategoryRow.swift`, and embed everything into `NavigationView`: `NavigationView -> ScrollView -> HStack -> ForEach -> NavigationLink`, the preview will display `Preview Crushed`. Anyone knows why?